# Create Jqplot Line chart in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqplot

This is the string i am getting for Json. Please suggest how can i use this to create Jqplot Line chart in mvc4 with razor c#. The x-axis is datestring (i.e. 3 Pm, 4 PM, etc) and y-axis is Demand value.

```
[{"Demand":4422.45,"Supply":17660,"Date":"\/Date(1236504600000)\/","DateString":"3 PM"},
{"Demand":5019.27,"Supply":20699,"Date":"\/Date(1236508200000)\/","DateString":"4 PM"},
{"Demand":5030.35,"Supply":19917,"Date":"\/Date(1236511800000)\/","DateString":"5 PM"},
{"Demand":5172.35,"Supply":23597,"Date":"\/Date(1236515400000)\/","DateString":"6 PM"},
{"Demand":5656.51,"Supply":21572,"Date":"\/Date(1236519000000)\/","DateString":"7 PM"},
{"Demand":4622.88,"Supply":7794,"Date":"\/Date(1236522600000)\/","DateString":"8 PM"},
{"Demand":3116.21,"Supply":3427,"Date":"\/Date(1236526200000)\/","DateString":"9 PM"},
{"Demand":1588.83,"Supply":1883,"Date":"\/Date(1236529800000)\/","DateString":"10 PM"},
{"Demand":1394.15,"Supply":1403,"Date":"\/Date(1236533400000)\/","DateString":"11 PM"},
{"Demand":1321.76,"Supply":3755,"Date":"\/Date(1236537000000)\/","DateString":"12 AM"},
{"Demand":1130.98,"Supply":3474,"Date":"\/Date(1236540600000)\/","DateString":"1 AM"},
{"Demand":1277.1,"Supply":1072,"Date":"\/Date(1236544200000)\/","DateString":"2 AM"},
{"Demand":1214.68,"Supply":1025,"Date":"\/Date(1236547800000)\/","DateString":"3 AM"},
{"Demand":2117.91,"Supply":1198,"Date":"\/Date(1236551400000)\/","DateString":"4 AM"},
{"Demand":1658.97,"Supply":1485,"Date":"\/Date(1236555000000)\/","DateString":"5 AM"},
{"Demand":1997.36,"Supply":3126,"Date":"\/Date(1236558600000)\/","DateString":"6 AM"},
{"Demand":2147.37,"Supply":4785,"Date":"\/Date(1236562200000)\/","DateString":"7 AM"},
{"Demand":2114.13,"Supply":5268,"Date":"\/Date(1236565800000)\/","DateString":"8 AM"},
{"Demand":2389.84,"Supply":5264,"Date":"\/Date(1236569400000)\/","DateString":"9 AM"},
{"Demand":2240.77,"Supply":5526,"Date":"\/Date(1236573000000)\/","DateString":"10 AM"},
{"Demand":1802.43,"Supply":4530,"Date":"\/Date(1236576600000)\/","DateString":"11 AM"},
{"Demand":1929.71,"Supply":6618,"Date":"\/Date(1236580200000)\/","DateString":"12 PM"},
{"Demand":545.65,"Supply":2767,"Date":"\/Date(1236583800000)\/","DateString":"1 PM"},
{"Demand":0,"Supply":1,"Date":"\/Date(1236587400000)\/","DateString":"2 PM"}]
```

Edit: the code

```
            <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
            <script src="~/Scripts/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <link href="~/Content/jquery.jqplot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqPlot/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqPlot/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqPlot/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

            var rawData = [{ "Demand": 4422.45, "Supply": 17660, "Date": "/Date(1236504600000)/", "DateString": "3 PM" }, { "Demand": 5019.27, "Supply": 20699, "Date": "/Date(1236508200000)/", "DateString": "4 PM" }, { "Demand": 5030.35, "Supply": 19917, "Date": "/Date(1236511800000)/", "DateString": "5 PM" }, { "Demand": 5172.35, "Supply": 23597, "Date": "/Date(1236515400000)/", "DateString": "6 PM" }, { "Demand": 5656.51, "Supply": 21572, "Date": "/Date(1236519000000)/", "DateString": "7 PM" }, { "Demand": 4622.88, "Supply": 7794, "Date": "/Date(1236522600000)/", "DateString": "8 PM" }, { "Demand": 3116.21, "Supply": 3427, "Date": "/Date(1236526200000)/", "DateString": "9 PM" }, { "Demand": 1588.83, "Supply": 1883, "Date": "/Date(1236529800000)/", "DateString": "10 PM" }, { "Demand": 1394.15, "Supply": 1403, "Date": "/Date(1236533400000)/", "DateString": "11 PM" }, { "Demand": 1321.76, "Supply": 3755, "Date": "/Date(1236537000000)/", "DateString": "12 AM" }, { "Demand": 1130.98, "Supply": 3474, "Date": "/Date(1236540600000)/", "DateString": "1 AM" }, { "Demand": 1277.1, "Supply": 1072, "Date": "/Date(1236544200000)/", "DateString": "2 AM" }, { "Demand": 1214.68, "Supply": 1025, "Date": "/Date(1236547800000)/", "DateString": "3 AM" }, { "Demand": 2117.91, "Supply": 1198, "Date": "/Date(1236551400000)/", "DateString": "4 AM" }, { "Demand": 1658.97, "Supply": 1485, "Date": "/Date(1236555000000)/", "DateString": "5 AM" }, { "Demand": 1997.36, "Supply": 3126, "Date": "/Date(1236558600000)/", "DateString": "6 AM" }, { "Demand": 2147.37, "Supply": 4785, "Date": "/Date(1236562200000)/", "DateString": "7 AM" }, { "Demand": 2114.13, "Supply": 5268, "Date": "/Date(1236565800000)/", "DateString": "8 AM" }, { "Demand": 2389.84, "Supply": 5264, "Date": "/Date(1236569400000)/", "DateString": "9 AM" }, { "Demand": 2240.77, "Supply": 5526, "Date": "/Date(1236573000000)/", "DateString": "10 AM" }, { "Demand": 1802.43, "Supply": 4530, "Date": "/Date(1236576600000)/", "DateString": "11 AM" }, { "Demand": 1929.71, "Supply": 6618, "Date": "/Date(1236580200000)/", "DateString": "12 PM" }, { "Demand": 545.65, "Supply": 2767, "Date": "/Date(1236583800000)/", "DateString": "1 PM" }, { "Demand": 0, "Supply": 1, "Date": "/Date(1236587400000)/", "DateString": "2 PM" }];

            var plotData = []

            for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
                plotData[i] = [rawData[i].DateString, rawData[i].Demand, rawData[i].Supply];
            }

            var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [plotData], {
                title: 'Title of the Chart',
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                        label: "Date"
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        label: "Demand"
                    }
                },
                highlighter: {
                    show: true,
                    sizeAdjust: 7.5
                },
                cursor: {
                    show: false
                }
            });
            });

            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div>
            <div id="chart1" style="height:400px;width:600px; "></div>  
            </div>
            </body>
```

I want to create a line chart with two lines, one for demand and another one for supply. Previously i was using CanvasAxisLabelRenderer javascript files but with date values i was not able to display the chart. Please advice.
Once again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer really depends on exactly how you want to handle the `DateString` fields. If you just want it to display as is, e.g., "9 AM", then you could use something like this:

```
var rawData = [{"Demand":4422.45,"Supply":17660,"Date":"/Date(1236504600000)/","DateString":"3 PM"},{"Demand":5019.27,"Supply":20699,"Date":"/Date(1236508200000)/","DateString":"4 PM"},{"Demand":5030.35,"Supply":19917,"Date":"/Date(1236511800000)/","DateString":"5 PM"},{"Demand":5172.35,"Supply":23597,"Date":"/Date(1236515400000)/","DateString":"6 PM"},{"Demand":5656.51,"Supply":21572,"Date":"/Date(1236519000000)/","DateString":"7 PM"},{"Demand":4622.88,"Supply":7794,"Date":"/Date(1236522600000)/","DateString":"8 PM"},{"Demand":3116.21,"Supply":3427,"Date":"/Date(1236526200000)/","DateString":"9 PM"},{"Demand":1588.83,"Supply":1883,"Date":"/Date(1236529800000)/","DateString":"10 PM"},{"Demand":1394.15,"Supply":1403,"Date":"/Date(1236533400000)/","DateString":"11 PM"},{"Demand":1321.76,"Supply":3755,"Date":"/Date(1236537000000)/","DateString":"12 AM"},{"Demand":1130.98,"Supply":3474,"Date":"/Date(1236540600000)/","DateString":"1 AM"},{"Demand":1277.1,"Supply":1072,"Date":"/Date(1236544200000)/","DateString":"2 AM"},{"Demand":1214.68,"Supply":1025,"Date":"/Date(1236547800000)/","DateString":"3 AM"},{"Demand":2117.91,"Supply":1198,"Date":"/Date(1236551400000)/","DateString":"4 AM"},{"Demand":1658.97,"Supply":1485,"Date":"/Date(1236555000000)/","DateString":"5 AM"},{"Demand":1997.36,"Supply":3126,"Date":"/Date(1236558600000)/","DateString":"6 AM"},{"Demand":2147.37,"Supply":4785,"Date":"/Date(1236562200000)/","DateString":"7 AM"},{"Demand":2114.13,"Supply":5268,"Date":"/Date(1236565800000)/","DateString":"8 AM"},{"Demand":2389.84,"Supply":5264,"Date":"/Date(1236569400000)/","DateString":"9 AM"},{"Demand":2240.77,"Supply":5526,"Date":"/Date(1236573000000)/","DateString":"10 AM"},{"Demand":1802.43,"Supply":4530,"Date":"/Date(1236576600000)/","DateString":"11 AM"},{"Demand":1929.71,"Supply":6618,"Date":"/Date(1236580200000)/","DateString":"12 PM"},{"Demand":545.65,"Supply":2767,"Date":"/Date(1236583800000)/","DateString":"1 PM"},{"Demand":0,"Supply":1,"Date":"/Date(1236587400000)/","DateString":"2 PM"}];

var plotData = []

for(var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
    plotData[i] = [rawData[i].DateString, rawData[i].Demand];
}
```

At this point you should be able to use `plotData` as input to jqplot.

**Edit:**

So the trick here is to correctly parse a date from the `Date` field and set the hours with `DateString`. Try this in your for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
    //Parse the date.
    var date = new Date(+rawData[i].Date.match(/\d+/));
    //Grab the hour string.
    var hour = +rawData[i].DateString.match(/\d+/);
    //Figure out if this is PM.
    var isPm = rawData[i].DateString.indexOf("PM") > -1;

    //Set the hours property, but add 12 if this is PM.
    date.setHours(hour + (isPm ? 12 : 0));
    //The minutes should probably be zero.
    date.setMinutes(0);

    plotData[i] = [date, rawData[i].Demand, rawData[i].Supply];
}
```

Now to get your x-axis displaying ticks of the format `3 PM`, you need to set the `tickOptions` when configuring the axis:

```
tickOptions: { formatString: '%#I %p' }
```

If you are wanting to display a line for supply, I would recommend looking into using a second x-axis - this will allow you another axis on a scale appropriate for the data.

References:

- JavaScript Date Object: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- jqplot date formatting options: [jqplot Docs](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html)

Comment: Thanks nick_w for the reply. I was able to show the chart except that the values are not showing in proper order. I want to show 4422.45 as first point followed by other values in same order as supplied. Any idea how this can be done? Also it is showing the full date and not like this "3 PM". Please advice.

Comment: @user1254053 Can you post the code you are using to plot the graph - I can help you much faster that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot nick_w for your prompt reply, much appreciated. Added the code above.

Comment: @user1254053 I see you already edited your question with the code - good stuff. Let me know if my edit helps out.

Comment: Thanks nick_w, this is great! The chart shows the line as expected - taking first values as a starting point. Now the only thing is x-axis. Here the raw data is for 24 hours i.e. for every hour there is some data. So ideally it would be from 3PM to next day 2PM (24 hours). Now my chart shows this on x-axis:
12 PM 6 PM 12 AM 6 AM 12 PM 6 PM 12 AM
Not sure why there is 12 AM so many times. 
Thank you very much for your help, appreciate it!

Comment: @user1254053 No problem. Remember to come back and accept this as the answer. Keep in mind that you can also use the options described [here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis) to configure the x-axis. Specifically, you could use `min`, `max`, `numberTicks` and `tickInterval` to better configure the axis.